# In iOS, is Gamekitframework faster than multipeerconnectivity framework in sending messages?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gamekit, multipeer-connectivity

Using both the frameworks, we can send messages to session.peers using Bluetooth?

I am using multipeerconnectivity framework to send messages to my peers, but it usually has a delay of 1.4 sec between sending a message and receiving.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with GameKit recently, but switched to Multipeerconnectivity some time ago, since I only needed the peer connectivity aspect for my app [Race by Hearts](http://www.racebyhearts.com)

However in my experience with these frameworks I have never seen delays like the one you mention. It has always been really fast.

Are you perhaps experiencing some threading issues? Something blocking your main thread, delaying the effect of the incoming data?
Are you using reliable or unreliable delivery? Or perhaps streaming?

Comment: Since delay is a concern, I am using unreliable delivery.

Comment: How much data are you sending through each transmission?

Comment: I am experiencing same delays in streaming, even in sendData function i observe delays for 0.7 seconds